# Email confirmation link not working in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, confirmation, email-confirmation

I'm working on a custom page template with email confirmation. Everything works fine except when I click the link in the email, it gives me "page not found".

What's the problem in the PHP scripts?

Here's the snippet:

```
ob_start();
$email= '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!($_POST['subscriptions']=="")){
    $email= isset($_POST['subscriptions']) ? $_POST['subscriptions'] : '';

function encryptLink($stringValue){
    $key = "12345";
    $qryStr = "subscriptions=".$stringValue;
    $query = base64_encode(urlencode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $qryStr, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))));
    $link = 'www.example.com/testEnvironment/confirmation/'.$query;

    return $link;
    }
    $string = $email;
    $pagelink = encryptLink($string);

    //Email Details
    $mail_to = $email;
    $from_mail = "dummyemail@example.com";
    $from_name = "";
    $reply_to = "";
    $subject = "Confirmation";
    $message_body =
'Hey,

<span style="overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;">'.$pagelink.'</span>';

    //Generate a boundary
    $boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

    //Email Header
    $header = "From: ".$from_mail." \r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
    $header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";

    //Multipart wraps the Email Content
    $message_body .= "\r\n\r\n";
    $message_body  .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
    $message_body  .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
    $message_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
    $message_body  .= "\r\n";
    $message_body .= "$message_body\r\n";
    $message_body .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

        //Send email
        if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message_body, $header)){
            echo "Sent";
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Confirmation page PHP snippet:

```
$key = "12345";

$queryString = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), urldecode(base64_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

parse_str($queryString);

if(!empty($stringValue)){
  echo $stringValue;
} else{
  exit("Invalid parameters passed");
}
```

Comment: Well.. obviously the page isn't found, make sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Which framework are you using? What are the names for your files? Because by the looks of it you are not using any frameworks, which means that you'd have to implement the URL structure yourself which I seem to doubt.

Comment: Is the server ( presumably apache ) set up to look for such a page ie: `.htaccess - rewrite rules`?

Comment: I might have missed it, but where have you defined `$subscriptions`? You set it to be `$string = $subscriptions;`, but I can't find where that is defined.

Comment: @Jordy im creating custom page template in wordpress

Comment: @Epodax, I double checked the URL and it's correct

Comment: @Qirel, i just replace now, but still same issue

Comment: Okay, well that's valueable information, make sure to add these tags right away please @User014019

Comment: @Jordy its already there :)

Comment: @RamRaider i only have this in my htaccess... <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testEnvironment/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testEnvironment/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: ok - so you generate a link similar to this `www.example.com/testEnvironment/confirmation/byVFMCUwRSVBOVVDNCU3RiUwQSVEQSVDOGclOUMlQTklMEZZJTg2JTkxJTk3JUI1JUM3JURFJTAxJTIyJUExJUIxJUNGJTA2JUQ2JUMwJTdFJURF` ? how is the base64_encoded string to be recognised by the server ??

Comment: You might try with `http://` prepended.

Comment: @RamRaider Yes it's correct. I tried the suggestion of Srinath Reddy Dudi but it's give me "Invalid parameters passed"

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using a link for which the server is unprepared - the base64 encoded string appears to be a page or directory in the url generated and as it is random will not exist - hence the need for a rewrite rule and associated logic in php.

In the htaccess file perhaps a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testEnvironment/   
RewriteRule ^confirmation/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ confirmation/index.php?data=$1 [NC,L]
/* this will need to be adjusted to your url - is it simply confirmation.php or other? */
```

Notice `data`!

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['data'] ) ){

        $data=$_GET['data'];
        $key = "12345";


        $queryString = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ), urldecode( base64_decode( $data ) ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $key ) ) ), "\0");


        /* there is no return value from parse_str() so you would need to manually retrieve the variables to find `subscriptions` */
        parse_str( $queryString );


        /* does this show anything ? */
        print_r( $queryString );


        /*
        if(!empty( $stringValue )){
          print_r( $stringValue );
        } else{
          exit("Invalid parameters passed");
        }
        */          
    }
?>


My test environment
-------------------

## .htaccess ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stackconfirm/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ /test/stackconfirm.php?data=$1 [NC,L]



/* PHP script to generate email and confirmation link*/

function encryptLink( $stringValue ){
    $key = "12345";
    $qryStr = "subscriptions=".$stringValue;
    $query = base64_encode( urlencode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ), $qryStr, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $key ) ) ) ) );

    /* for my test I changed this portion to match url structure on test server */
    $link = '/stackconfirm/'.$query;
    return $link;
}


$link=encryptLink('bobby.dazzler@razzledazzle.com');
echo "<a href='$link'>Click here to confirm membership</a>";



stackconfirm.php
----------------

<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['data'] ) ){

        $data=$_GET['data'];
        $key = "12345";

        $queryString = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $key ), urldecode( base64_decode( $data ) ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $key ) ) ), "\0");

        echo '<pre>', $data, PHP_EOL, print_r( $queryString,true ), '</pre>';
    }
?>


Result
------
subscriptions=bobby.dazzler@razzledazzle.com
```

Comment: it's not echoing the $stringValue even the successful message... if(!empty($stringValue)){
 echo $stringValue;
 echo "pass";
 } else {
  exit("Invalid parameters passed");
 }
}

Comment: but are you getting anything there now in the confirmation page?

Comment: no. I just only get a blank page without any confirmation message

Comment: I changed the _GET since i'm using _POST in my form

Comment: No - you are clicking a link in the email are you not? Thus it is GET

Comment: I'm clicking a link from the email even i back it in _GET, still same issue

Comment: try `print_r( $queryString )`

Comment: couldn't display the value of $queryString using print_r, same issue exist

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating your key with the confirmation url directly. It will always lead to a 404 error page because the link doesn't exists.
Instead you can get the query via get request and process it in the confirmation script as follows.

```
$link = 'www.example.com/confirmation/?key='.$query;
```

In the confirmation script get the query via get method as follows.

```
$key=$_GET['key'];
```

Let the original key will be stored as `$original_key=12345;`
Now check whether the passed key is similar to the original key as

```
if($key==$original_key)
{
//confirm e-mail
}
else
{
//invalid key
}
```

Comment: I get this message "Invalid parameters passed"